# My for of loop keeps stopping after 1 iteration

Tags: for-loop, ecmascript-6, for-of-loop

For some reason or another, my for of loop continues stopping after 1 iteration.

I'm expecting to get a console.log of 2 assetId's and 2 prices, however instead I'm only getting 1 assetId and 1 price. Then the only way I can get a response that suits is when I re-run the function via refresh (b/c it checks my localStorage and sees the old values are already there) any ideas why it's stopping after one iteration?

```
   main = async () => {
        await eth.connect({
          provider: "https://mainnet.infura.io/[key-goes-here]",
          contracts: [landRegistry, marketplace]
        });


    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://api.decentraland.org/parcels?status=open"
    );
    const viableProperties = response.data.data.parcels.filter(parcel => parcel.publication.price <= this.state.landPrice);
    for(let [key, value] of viableProperties.entries()) {
      const cost = value.publication.price;
      const asset = value.publication.asset_id;
      const commaPos = asset.indexOf(",");
      const coordinatesLat = parseFloat(asset.substring(0, commaPos));
      const coordinatesLong = parseFloat(
        asset.substring(commaPos + 1, asset.length)
      );
      const price = eth.utils.toWei(cost);
      const oldProperty = localStorage.getItem(asset)
      if (cost <= this.state.landPrice && oldProperty == null) {
        localStorage.setItem(asset, key);
        const assetId = await landRegistry.encodeTokenId(
          coordinatesLat,
          coordinatesLong
        );
        await marketplace.executeOrder(assetId, price)
      }
    } 
  };
```

**** EDIT ****  - where I currently have await marketplace.executeOrder...I used to have console.log(asset, price)

Comment: When you do `console.log(viableProperties)`, right before the start of the `for` loop what do you see?

Comment: Please don't just post and disappear.  I'm trying to help you, but asked you a question in service of trying to help and you're not answering. Since you may be new here, this is not like other online forums where you post and come back the next day. You need to check back multiple times within the hour after you post to see if anyone has asked clarifying questions or if someone is offering to help, but needs some engagement to work it out. The majority of people will see your question in the first 30 minutes after you post. If you're not here then to engage people who respond, u will miss out.

Comment: ah sorry about that, wasn't aware! I see an array of objects that are pulled from the API get call:
0
:
{id: "55,-87", x: 55, y: -87, auction_price: 1000, district_id: null, …}
1
:
{id: "-150,-91", x: -150, y: -91, auction_price: 1000, district_id: null, …}
2
:
{id: "-150,-90", x: -150, y: -90, auction_price: 1000, district_id: null, …}

Comment: Then put a `console.log("top of for loop", key, value)` as the first line in the `for` loop.  You need to debug this yourself and see what's going on.  We can't do that for you.  If there are indeed multiple items in the `viableProperties` array, then your `for` loop is running multiple times.  It's probably your `if` statement that only find one value that passes the condition.

Comment: "If there are indeed multiple items in the viableProperties array, then your for loop is running multiple times." That's not true. viableProperties is just the result of filtering the initial array that comes back from the GET call

Comment: You're running a `for` loop on `viableProperties`.  In my first comment, I asked you to do `console.log(viableProperties)` on the line before the `for` loop.  Are you seeing multiple items in that array or not?  I don't care what your API returns.  You're running the `for` loop on `viableProperties` so we need to see what's in that.  That's what matters here.  Unless you are modifying `viableProperties` inside the `for` loop which it doesn't appear you are, then the `for` loop will run for each item in that array.  That's what `for/of` does.

Comment: Yes I'm seeing multiple items. "When you do console.log(viableProperties), right before the start of the for loop what do you see?" was your first question. Thats only going to list the results of the filter function, it has nothing do with the for loop if the code is pasted above the for loop

Comment: The `for` loop is iterating `viableProperties`!  I just want to know WHAT the `for` loop is iterating.  That's what matters to the `for` loop.  So, what do you see when you put `console.log("top of for loop", key, value);` as the first line in the `for` loop

Comment: top of for loop 0 {id: "55,-87", x: 55, y: -87, auction_price: 1000, district_id: null, …}
App.js:98 top of for loop 1 {id: "26,-120", x: 26, y: -120, auction_price: 1564, district_id: null, …}
App.js:98 top of for loop 2 {id: "27,-120", x: 27, y: -120, auction_price: 1000, district_id: null, …}
App.js:98 top of for loop 3 {id: "-62,-9", x: -62, y: -9, auction_price: 1563, district_id: null, …}

Comment: So, your `for` loop is running multiple times.  Have we now disproven the hypothesis in the title of your question?  Now, if something is only happening once in all those iterations, it must be because of your `if` statement.  I hope you can use your own `console.log()` debugging to figure it out from here.  You really should learn how to use the debugger and then you could just step through each iteration of the loop one line at a time and watch exactly what it's doing.

Comment: yeah fair enough thanks for the help. It has something to do with the await function at the very bottom. The code I had pasted above had a console.log in it's place that i had forgot to change. Some issue with either my async function or metamask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, now that you've shown us the real code with the:

```
await marketplace.executeOrder(assetId, price)
```

in it, there is a plausible reason for the `for` loop to stop.  If the promise that `marketplace.executeOrder()` returns, rejects or if it throws a synchronous exception, then the `async` function will immediately reject its promise and stop executing anything further.

If you want the loop to continue even if that promise fails, you can catch the rejected promise with either a `try/catch` or a `.catch()`.

---

Please take this as future advice to include as much of your real code as possible in the question.  If you leave things out that you think aren't part of the issue, you may just be hiding the real issue from the people that are trying to help you (this happens a lot here and it really slows down our ability to help).

Comment: sounds good I'll give that a shot! and thanks for being patient with me, you've been real helpful and I appreciate that. Advice taken.

Comment: @new2leGame - If this (and my other comments) answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.